# convert a pinescript v2 script to pinescript v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I can't convert this script to v5, do you have any ideas on how I can do it?

```
//@version=2
strategy("Fractal Breakout Strategy (by ChartArt)", shorttitle="CA_-_Fractal_Breakout_Strat", overlay=true)

// input
n_time = input(title='Always exit each trade after this amount of bars later (Most important strategy setting)', defval=3, type=integer)
price = input(hl2,title='Price type to determine the last fractal top and the fractal breakout, the default is (high+low)/2')


// fractal calculation
fractal_top = high[2] > high[3] and high[2] > high[4] and high[2] > high[1] and high[2] > high[0]
fractal_price = valuewhen(fractal_top, price, 1)
use_longer_average = input(true,title='Use Fractal price average of the last 3 fractals instead of the last 2 fractals?')
fractal_average = use_longer_average?(fractal_price[1] + fractal_price[2] + fractal_price[3] ) / 3 : (fractal_price[1] + fractal_price[2]) / 2
fractal_trend = fractal_average[0] > fractal_average[1]
no_repainting = input(true,title='Use the price of the last bar to prevent repainting?')
fractal_breakout = no_repainting?price[1] > fractal_price[0]:price[0] > fractal_price[0]


// highlight fractal tops
show_highlight = input(true,title='Highlight fractal tops in blue and color all other bars in gray?')
highlight = fractal_top?blue:silver
barcolor(show_highlight?highlight:na,offset=-2)
show_fractal_top_line = input(true,title='Draw a colored line based on the fractal tops?')
fractal_top_line = change(fractal_top) != 0 ? price : na
fractal_top_line_color = change(fractal_price) > 0 and fractal_breakout == true ? green : change(fractal_price) < 0 and fractal_breakout == false ? red : blue
plot(show_fractal_top_line?fractal_top_line:na,offset=-2,color=fractal_top_line_color,linewidth=4)

// strategy
trade_entry = fractal_trend and fractal_breakout
trade_exit = fractal_trend[n_time] and fractal_trend == false 
 
if (trade_entry)
    strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)
 
if (trade_exit)
    strategy.close('Long')
```

I tried to convert it to v3 and then go through the trading view converter but I can't find the same results!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so we can tell you what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Do you still require assistance with this or did you manage to resolve?

Comment: I have found an alternative. Thank you all!